# Не могу установить PyGame в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pip, pygame

Во вкладке `Terminal` в `PyCharm` я вводил

```
pip3.8 install pygame
pip3 install pygame
pip install pygame
```

И всегда получал вот такую ошибку:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /sysroot/home/user/PycharmProject/???/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ltp9j88k/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ltp9j88k/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-un0ew218
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ltp9j88k/pygame/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...
    
    /bin/sh: sdl-config: команда не найдена
    /bin/sh: sdl-config: команда не найдена
    /bin/sh: sdl-config: команда не найдена
    
    Hunting dependencies...
    WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
    Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

В обычном Linux терминале у меня получилось установить `pygame` через `pip`
Если эту проблему не удастся решить, то напишите Python модуль для обработки событий клавиатуры который вы знаете

Comment: В *settings->python interpreter* поставьте virtualenv со всеми нужными пакетами с помощью графического интерфейса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В PyCharm Pro 2020.2.2 установить PyGame можно вот так:

- File
- Settings
- Project
- Python Interpreter
- [+]
- pygame
- Install Package

[image: PyGame в PyCharm]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете просто на первой строчке написать import pygame и слева будет такая лампочка нажимаете на нее и высвечивается install pygame